# Insert numbers below each column of a histogram

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis

I am trying to plot a histogram by below lines

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
 \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
 \draw[<-] (7,0) node[below] {$x$} -- (-.5,0);
 \draw[->] (0,-.5) -- (0,7) node[left] {$y$};
 \draw (0,0) grid (6,1)  (1,1) grid (2,6)  (3,1) grid (4,5) (4,1) 
  rectangle (5,2);

 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

whose extracted output is as Fig.1 (of course without the red numbers below x axis).

[image: Fig.1]

How do I insert red numbers by latex (not paint) exactly below each column, however they are not starting with 1. Instead, they begin for example from 11 here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
 \draw[<-] (7,0) node[below] {$x$} -- (-.5,0);
 \draw[->] (0,-.5) -- (0,7) node[left] {$y$};
 \draw (0,0) grid (6,1)  (1,1) grid (2,6)  (3,1) grid (4,5) (4,1) 
  rectangle (5,2);
 \foreach \i in {10,...,15}
    \path[red] (\i-9.5,0) node[below] {$\i$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]